# Google Analytics Reporting API v4: Difference in return values for same period

Tags: rest, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I trying to perform request for specified date range.

For example: from 1 May 2017 till 5 May 2017

I do it in two ways:

**First way:** one request with date range:

```
2017-05-01 ~ 2017-05-05
```

**Second way:** four requests with date ranges:

```
2017-05-01 ~ 2017-05-02
2017-05-02 ~ 2017-05-03
2017-05-03 ~ 2017-05-04
2017-05-04 ~ 2017-05-05
```

As I expect the total sum of metrics (ga:sessions, etc) should be equal.

I.e. total number of sessions in first way should  be equal to the sum of sessions from second way:

```
sessions from 2017-05-01 ~ 2017-05-02 +
sessions from 2017-05-02 ~ 2017-05-03 +
sessions from 2017-05-03 ~ 2017-05-04 +
sessions from 2017-05-04 ~ 2017-05-05
```

But this is not true.

Sum of sessions in second way much bigger.

What is the reason?

Actually, results from GA API are not sampled (no `reportData.samplesReadCounts` or `resportData.samplingSpaceSizes` fields in response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your date ranges should be exclusive, e.g. 01-02, 03-04 and so on. Try add ga:datehour to inspect particular differences